# what is wrong with this partially applied function attempt?

Tags: scala

I am trying to write a partially applied function. I thought the below would work but it doesn't. Grateful for any help.

```
scala> def doSth(f: => Unit) { f }
doSth: (f: => Unit)Unit

scala> def sth() = { println ("Hi there") }
sth: ()Unit

scala> doSth(sth)
Hi there

scala> val b = sth _
b: () => Unit = <function0>

scala> doSth(b)
<console>:11: warning: a pure expression does nothing in statement position; you may be omitting necessary parentheses
              doSth(b)
                    ^
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is subtle. `sth` is a method, so you can call it without the parentheses, which is what is happening here:

```
doSth(sth)
```

But `b` is just a function `() => Unit`, which you must use the parentheses to invoke.

```
doSth(b())
```

Otherwise you would not be able to assign `b` to another identifier.

```
val c: () => Unit = b
```

If we automatically invoked `b` here, `c` would be `Unit` instead of `() => Unit`. The ambiguity must be removed.

Let me also clarify that `doSth` is *not* a method that accepts only functions. `f: => Unit` means it accepts anything that evaluates to `Unit`, which *includes* methods that return `Unit` *when they are invoked.* `doSth(sth)` is *not* passing the message `sth` to `doSth`, it's invoking `sth` without parentheses and passing the result.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think you're right. I've defined doSth as a method that takes a function. When I pass it sth, it is doSth that executes sth in its function body. You can prove this by changing doSth to def doSth(f: => Unit) { println("Here first"); f } It will print 'Here first' and then 'Hi there'. I'm trying to do doSth(b) because I want it to pass b, a partially applied function, for execution. According to programming in scala, you can pass partially applied functions in this way (I thought) but I'm not getting it to work..

Comment: `f: => Unit` is **not** the same as a function that returns `Unit`. It is anything that produces `Unit` as a value. For example I can call `doSth(Unit)`, but I'm not passing a function, am I?

Comment: Ah, 1000 thanks, and apologies for saying you were wrong. I totally didn't get what f: => Unit is. I thought it was just like you can leave the () off a parameterless method. Ah, that explains everything.. Thanks again. Very much appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference is that `b` has type `() => Unit`, and `doSth` expects an expression that returns `Unit` (minor difference).  If you want to store `sth` as a variable without the side effects, you could do:

```
lazy val b = sth
doSth(b)
```

The other option would be to make it so that `doSth` takes in `() => Unit`:

```
def doSth(f: () => Unit) { f() }
def sth() = { println ("Hi there") }
doSth(sth)
val b = sth _
doSth(b)
```